# url redirection not happening in IE in crossrider extension

Tags: internet-explorer, url, firefox, crossrider, browser-tab

I am trying to open a url by using crossrider API in my extension

```
appAPI.openURL({
                url: mUrl,
                where: "tab",
                focus: true,
                height:window.screen.availHeight,
                width:window.screen.availWidth
});
```

I am trying to open url as new tab and getting the following error. and some parameters from my url are missing when i see my server accesslog.

This works fine in firefox though.

[image: Error image]

Comment: In general, the openURL method works fine in IE. It may be a problem with your URL/server, however, from your question it's not possible to tell which URL you are opening (_mUrl_ is not defined) and you haven't mentioned which scope the code appears in (_extension.js_, _background.js_ ...). Also note, when opening a URL in a tab the height and width properties have no meaning. If you need further help with this, please provide the aforementioned information and I'll be happy to help. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: @Shlomo Yes it is working fine and i tested it with a test url.

to say if something is wrong with my Url, that is working in Firefox. so i am little bit confused.

any suggestions!!

Comment: Please provide the URL you are testing with and I will be happy to check.